# InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: One or more TimeSeries could not be written:

Tags: java, exception, google-cloud-platform, grpc

**Details**: I get strange warnings in logs which occur every few minutes with different values. The message I encounter is from the Google Cloud Monitoring API when trying to write time series data. The specific problem is with the distribution values in the time series as in example below:

```
InvalidArgumentException: io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: INVALID_ARGUMENT: 
One or more TimeSeries could not be written: Field 
timeSeries[7].points[0].distributionValue had an 
invalid value: Distribution value has 
|bucket_counts| fields that sum to 6 which does not 
equal the |count| field value of 4.
```

**Question**: Did anyone encounter this before and knows the reason or solution?

Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Are you using [GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java)? If so, similar [issues](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/opentelemetry-operations-java/issues?q=is%3Aissue+%22INVALID_ARGUMENT%3A+One+or+more+TimeSeries+could+not+be+written%22) have been reported from that library. Consider filing an issue there if this is a unique issue.

Comment: While you're receiving a gRPC error, I think this isn't an issue with gRPC but an issue with a library that uses gRPC. If so, the `grpc` tag is misleading. I think tags should be used to focus attention on the question to relevant audiences not to describe the technologies being used.